# Understanding an awk expression

Tags: linux, awk

I have never used awk uptill now.
I encountered an awk script recently that says
`{Some previous command}| awk -W interactive '{print} /Please press CTRL\+C to exit./ {print "Exiting."; system("kill " system("echo "))}'`
I have to make this script run on windows.
But i dont even know what it does.
Any help appreciated, and please dont tell me to go and search the man pages which i have already done and it all seems to much complicated.
I just grasped that it is some form of a pattern action statement.
If any awk pro knows what is going on please let me know.
And if possible will i be able to run this script on windows.

Comment: Install cygwin and run awk in it directly.

Comment: Not possible i want to do it with minimal dependencies.I have cygwin already installed.And if you know this awk statement please explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That seems very strange

Basically, the awk code looks like it spits out every line of input (with the `{print}` directive), as it sees it in line-buffered mode (`-W interactive`).

When it comes accross the `Please press CTRL+C to exit.` line, it informs the terminal and attempts execute the rather odd system commands.

```
print "Exiting."; system("kill " system("echo "))
```

Perhaps I'm misreading this, but it looks like that should devolve to `kill 0` if the `echo` command succeeds. [Kill 0 kills off everything in the current process group](https://superuser.com/questions/563972/what-does-kill-0-do-actually).

Comment: I am sorry for one forgotten aspect , `print "Exiting."; system("kill " system("echo "$SPID"))` -< where SPID is the current PID.Thanks for the answer.

Comment: No, `SIPD` contains the numeric value of a field in the current input record. If unset it has the value zero and so evaluates to `$0"` which would result in the entire record being passed to `echo` followed by whatever is between that last double quote and the next one. awk is NOT shell.